# What is the difference between svn import and checkout?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have used GIT for a long time and new to SVN. I couldn't find a which satisfy me the difference between svn import and checkout. Highly appreciate if someone can show me with an example. Thanks

Comment: Are you confusing "import" and "export"?

Comment: No actually plz go to here http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~vailen/svn_howto.htm#linux this is what making me annoying.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"import" and "checkout" are polar opposites.

"Import" is to bring something completely outside of version control into SVN.

Once something is under SVN control, you can "commit" (new modifications), or "checkout" (stuff you've already committed).

At any time, you can "export" some or all of your project into a "clean directory".  The source you've exported is *not* under version control.

You "import into" and "export out of" SVN.

You "commit" and "checkout" stuff that's already under SVN control.

Answer (score 4):

Import: Commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository.

Checkout: Check out a working copy from a repository.

Answer (score 4):

When you use CHECKOUT what you are doing it's donwloading and synctronizing a repository directory in your local machine.

IMPORT you are doing commit/uploading a local path into the repository